OpenDNS Settings for NOKIA Beacon 6 Router
I've set all our computers on our LAN to go via OpenDNS, but how do I set the NOKIA Beacon 6 Router?
On opening the Admin pages the Primary DNS is 1.1.1.1 and Secondary DNS 8.8.8.8 but these fields are not able to be edited and I'm not certain if this is where I need to change the DNS addresses to go via OpenDNS 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220
Screen shot showing LAN Settings page, but I cannot enter the Primary or Secondary DNS fields.
So that we can filter SmartPhones etc on the WiFi.
In other words, the whole home Network LAN will be filtered via OpenDNS.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you fill anything else on that page? The page seems to be editable to me. (Also, what else do you have under the LAN section and under the Advanced section?)
